# Mplayer video streaming from URL not working

Tags: video, mplayer

I am trying to stream a video from some URL.

```
mplayer -fs https://www.someurl.com/video.mp4
```

But it throws an error:

```
MPlayer2 2.0-728-g2c378c7-4+b1 (C) 2000-2012 MPlayer Team
Cannot open file '/home/fa/.mplayer/input.conf': No such file or directory
Failed to open /home/fa/.mplayer/input.conf.
Cannot open file '/etc/mplayer/input.conf': No such file or directory
Failed to open /etc/mplayer/input.conf.

Playing https://www.someurl.com/video.mp4.
No stream found to handle url https://www.someurl.com/video.mp4
```

I dont know why am I getting     **No stream found to handle url https://www.someurl.com/video.mp4** error.

Answer (score 0):

Anyways I got the answer, by adding **ffmpeg://**

```
mplayer -fs ffmpeg://https://www.someurl.com/video.mp4
```